# Flutter dart debugger breakpoints stopped working

Tags: android, debugging, dart, flutter, breakpoints

I'm learning Dart and Flutter and developing a small Android Flutter app under Android Studio 3.1.2. Suddenly debugger breakpoints stopped working - the app started in debug mode never stops on them, and the red dots indicating breakpoints change to red dots with x inside. The only place in my app where they still work is in the main.dart module.

I cleaned the project many times, tested on two different devices, uninstalled completely my Flutter debug app, and started new - nothing helps. Flutter update on beta (current beta 2) channel does nothing. Also tried switching to dev and master channels - no help.

Did anyone encounter a similar situation, how do deal with it?

Edit, adding mail.dart and output of flutter doctor (currently on the master branch, but have the same problem after switching to beta or dev branches):

Imports from main.dart, or better all of main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

import 'app_strings.dart';
import 'net_libs_page/net_libs_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
        AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        //FallbackMaterialLocalisationsDelegate(),
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', 'US'), // English
        Locale('es', 'ES'), // Spanish
        Locale('pl', 'PL'),
        // ... other locales the app supports
      ],
      title: '@Voice Network Library', //_strings.title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
        // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
      ),
      home: NetLibsPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, v0.4.5-pre.52, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.431], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] VS Code, 32-bit edition (version 1.19.3)
[√] Connected devices (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Please add the imports from your `lib/main.dart`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Günter! The only one that was not there was import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart'; and Android Studio indicated it was not used in the module where breakpoints don't work. Adding it did not change anything.

Comment: Please add the imports from your `lib/main.dart` to your question. Also the output of `flutter doctor`.

Comment: Just added, thank you for your willingness to help. What else I did: created new sample app - breakpoints work in it. Compared build.gradle - all of them, AndroidManifest.xml, pubspec.yaml - no important differences...

Comment: closing and reopening VS Code worked for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't use relative imports in `lib/main.dart`

```
import 'app_strings.dart';
import 'net_libs_page/net_libs_page.dart';
```

instead use

```
import 'package:my_app/app_strings.dart';
import 'package:my_app/net_libs_page/net_libs_page.dart';
```

where `my_app` is what is in `pubspec.yaml` in the `name:` field.

The issue where this is tracked https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33076

Comment: Wow!!! It works! Would never thought of this, particularly because it was this way for several weeks and worked fine, only stopped yesterday (after the code grew bigger???) I think that every beginner Flutter programmer should be also given a magic wand and instructions to mutter "abracadabra"  when trying to run his apps... Thank you again for your help!!!

Comment: Glad to hear :) This is a bit an unfortunate issue. Flutter is using Dart a bit differently than originally intended to make it easier for developers, but this requires changes in the language, but because of the work on Dart 2 there us some resource shortage. This will hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: whoah. this should be definitely a bug report. It suddenly stopped for me suddenly too

Comment: @alltooconfusingthereforesleep I added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Seems that capitalization for the path inside import path causes breakpoints to stop working. Ie:

```
package:myApp/model/myWidget/myWidget.dart
```

and

```
package:myApp/model/MyWidget/MyWidget.dart
```

are not the same for debugging. Funny thing is that the app launches without any problem with incorrect path capitalization.

Comment: Is that on MacOs? Note that macos has this strange feature where it does not care about path capitalization.

Comment: You save my day. It was my problem

Comment: Same. Thank you. Seems still a bug.

Answer (score 3):

For those who use flutter on VS Code,

please take a look at changes you've made regarding dart file names.

I was having the same issue on VS Code. it showed no compilation error, worked fine but breakpoint did not work.

while I was going through changes I made and I looked at few of dart files that  I changed to.

For example, I changed "Home.dart" to "home.dart",, and so on.

Even when you change files' names, VS Code sometimes doesn't reflect changes,

which means even though you changed Home.dart to home.dart,

left panel shows home.dart while right panel where it shows files you opened still shows "Home.dart"

pictures below explains everything I just address.

[image]

[image]

solution is to simply close all the dart files you opened, close VS Code, and reopen it. this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were no errors found by Flutter Doctor. After spending some time trying to solve it, the Android Studio showed me a normal message to update Dart and Plugins. After the updates, it was enough to restart Android Studio and voilá. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just hitting the same issue, flutter debugger never stop on the breakpoints. This happened after my original emulator corrupted and recreated a new emulator.

Solution that's working for me is simple.

```
delete all breakpoints, watchlist
close the vscode
flutter clean
restart vscode
```

How to debug on this issue if above not working for you?

1. Refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/4015#issuecomment-1151116891). Copied and pasted the content below for easy reference

```
- Created a new project using the Flutter: New Project command
- Added the following code to lib/main.dart

class TestClass {
  void foo() {
    print('foo');
  }
}

- Added a breakpoint to the print line
- Added the following code to the top of the test/widget_test.dart file in the existing test

TestClass().foo();

- Clicked the Debug link above the test
```

If above works, means there's something specific in your project that causing the debugger not working properly.

2. Make use of the devTool in web browser, use the debugger tool that comes with it to set your breakpoint, and see if it works.
3. use the dart programmatic breakpoint

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

yourFunc() {
  // ...
  debugger();
}
```

From there you may get some idea to fix that issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you use Powershell & VS Code and you are getting this warning:
"The casing of the open workspace..."

Say you have a folder called MY_APP, but you load your app from PowerShell inside the folder my_app, debug will not work, as is expecting the folder to be named MY_APP.

For me I just change the casing in Powershell and debug is working again.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that my code was inaccessible means there was no way to navigate to or run that code.

Then I added the navigator to navigate to that screen and it started working

Answer (score -1):

**Solution that worked for me:**

Simply

> uninstall your flutter app

from the real device (manually on the device) and try debugging again(!)